# mongstat Failed: not authorized on admin to execute command { serverStatus: 1, recordStats: 0 }

Tags: mongodb

After adding auth mongodb authentication , you can not use mongostat, with the following error : Failed: not authorized on admin to execute command {serverStatus: 1, recordStats: 0}
If you encounter this problem , the trouble to tell me how to solve Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With authentication enabled, you have to create a role (and a user with that role) that is sufficient to run `mongostat`.  The built-in [ClusterMonitor role](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterMonitor) will give you the required permissions.

There is a step by step guide to adding a role for `mongostat` in the docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#create-a-role-to-run-mongostat).  Similarly, you can find the [details](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#required-access) in the docs on how to run mongostat with [username](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#cmdoption--username) and [password](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#cmdoption--password) specified (or prompted).